How do I configure Python "ruff" to sensibly format Polars?
How do I configure Ruff to sensibly auto-format Python code for the Polars library?
With the default settings, it likes to left-align .select/.with_columns calls with many arguments. The following is how ruff/black both format it (which is difficult to read):
import polars as pl

df = df.select(
    event_type=pl.col("log_entry")
    .str.extract(r"Event Type: ([\w ]+)")
    .cast(pl.Utf8),
    event_duration=pl.col("log_entry")
    .str.extract(r"Duration: (\d+)")
    .cast(pl.Int32),
)


This is roughly how I want it to be formatted, if wrapping at 79 chars (note the indented additional operations:
df = df.select(
    event_type=pl.col("log_entry")
        .str.extract(r"Event Type: ([\w ]+)")
        .cast(pl.Utf8),
    event_duration=pl.col("log_entry")
        .str.extract(r"Duration: (\d+)")
        .cast(pl.Int32),
)


FWIW, Black does the same thing if you make the lines longer (for example by adding some extra characters after log_entry).

FWIW, you could wrap them in parentheses (event_type=(...)), then the whole thing gets indented. Not sure how helpful this is though since it's not "auto" formatting.

https://github.com/astral-sh/ruff/issues/8598 seems to be where all the discussion is.

as was already commented on your other question, one might have a discussion on what is "sensible" (subjective...), but the whole point of the formatter stays (IMHO) that you do not configure it. It's the "everybody hates it, everybody loves it" logic that go fmt exemplifies.
